# Repository Pattern with Generic interface and DI in EF

Tags: c#, generics, dependency-injection, repository-pattern

i have this existing code

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    void Create(T obj);
    T Retrieve(string key);
}


public class ItemRepository : IRepository<Item>
{
        public void Create(Item obj)
        {
            //codes
        }

        public Item Retrieve(string key)
        {
            //codes
        }    
}
```

i would like to create a General class repository where i have to inject a type of IRepository to the constructor then use its own implementation of the methods. i already have an existing code but it is currently wrong

```
    public class Repository
{
    IRepository<T> action = null;
    public Repository(IRepository<T> concreteImplementation)
    {
        this.action = concreteImplementation;
    }

    public void Create(T obj)
    {
        action.Create(obj);
    }
}
```

the classes are from EF. if there is no work around for this what will be the best approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want a single repository which can create or retrieve an object of any type by delegating to a type specific repository implementation?

How do you imagine this working? you defined this `Repository` class, but you have to create a concrete implementation of the actual repository in order to use it, and then still have to create an instance of `Repository` anyway. Why not just use the generic implementation you have to create anyway?

And what about your `Retrieve` method?  How will this look in your `Repository` class?  Will you just return `Object`? or will you make your method generic?

Anyway to answer your question, you could do this I suppose:

```
public class Repository
{
    IRepository action = null;
    public Repository(IRepository concreteImplementation)
    {
        this.action = concreteImplementation;
    }

    public void Create<T>(T obj)
    {
        action.Create(obj);
    }
}
```

but you have to introduce a non generic interface as well, as you can't require an interface with a generic parameter in the constructor without specifying the generic type on the class.

```
public interface IRepository
{
    void Create(object obj);
    object Retrieve(string key);
}
```

Or possibly you could pass in the type into the Create method instead of having a generic parameter:

```
public class Repository
{
    IRepository action = null;
    public Repository(IRepository concreteImplementation, Type respositoryType)
    {
        this.action = concreteImplementation;
        expectedType=repositoryType;
    }

    public void Create(Type type, Object obj)
    {
        if(type==expected && obj.GetType()==type)
        {
            action.Create(obj);
        }
    }
}
```

but both of these are terrible ideas. Just use the generics and create a repository per type, it'll be best in the long run

Comment: i was practicing DI based from this
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/615139/An-Absolute-Beginners-Tutorial-on-Dependency-Inver
but it seems not applicable to Generics. anyways thank you for the answer. creating separate repositories will do for me

Answer (score 0):

I think you might just be missing the definition of `T` in the context of the general repository class.

Try adding `<T>` to the it like this:

```
public class Repository<T>
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: Yes i know but if i specify a T and make an instance of it then it then i dont have to inject a concreteimplementation and i have to create a repository for each entity. do you know any work around to this?